# Is there a way to restrain a physics body inside of a regular n-gon?

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm building a simple game in which I am generating n-gons around a ball and then dragging the ball around the inside the n-gon to collide with the walls. I want the ball to follow my finger but not to leave the n-gon when my finger goes outside of the n-gon. Instead, if my finder is outside of the shape the ball should track my finger by sliding along to wall at the same radian as my finger position.

I have added physics objects to both the ball and to all of the walls, however my movement script for the ball currently sets the ball's position to the touch position and because of this the ball with teleport outside of the shape if the finger is moved outside the shape.

I have already tried to add large rectangular physics objects to the outside of each wall of the shape in an attempt to prevent the ball from teleporting there, however this just causes the physics object to freak out and glitch all over the place.

Is the a better way to control the ball to keep it inside the n-gon?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You will always hit problems if you  are suing physics to restrict and object's movement whilst simultaneously setting the object's position directly. Why not use an SKAction to move the ball towards the location of the touch? Then the movement of the ball can be stopped when it hits something. You could also set up contact detection and remove the movement action when you detect the ball colliding with something.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My current plan for the problem is to detect if the touch is outside of the n-gon by drawing a line from the center to the touch and checking if it intersects with any of the wall paths. Then if there is an intersection I calculate where it is and place the ball next to it inside the n-gon.

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this Issue was by checking if the finger position was inside of the n-gon by constructing a very slim rectangle from the center to the finger like so:

```
func updateRadianRect(fingerPos: CGPoint) {
        radianRect.removeFromParent()

// find the length of the rectangle
        let length = CGFloat(round(100 * (CGFloat(pow(fingerPos.x - center.x, 2) + pow(fingerPos.y - center.y, 2)).squareRoot())) / 100)

//create rectangle with given parameters
        radianRect = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: length))

//place the rectangle at our center point
        radianRect.position = CGPoint(x: tether.x, y: tether.y)

//determine the rotation needed to line up with the touch position
        if fingerPos.x > center.x {
            radianRect.zRotation = atan((fingerPos.y - center.y) / (fingerPos.x - center.x)) - (.pi / 2)
        } else if fingerPos.x < center.y {
            radianRect.zRotation = atan((fingerPos.y - center.y) / (fingerPos.x - center.x)) + (.pi / 2)
        }

        radianRect.lineWidth = 0
        addChild(radianRect)
    }
```

then using the "intersects" function for each wall to check if the finger was inside (intersected with at least 1 wall) or outside (didn't intersect with any walls).

side note: the reason that this has to be a slim rectangle instead of just a path, is because the intersects function can only take in two rectangles. so inputing a path would just generate a rectangle around the two points which gets very frustrating. Because of this the walls of the n-gons (or whatever you want to intersect) must also be a rectangle.

If it doesn't intersect, we can explicitly set the ball position to the finger position. However, if it does intersect, we can use the coordinates of the wall position, the touch position, and our center point to calculate where the ball should be placed inside of the n-gon while still tracking the finger. To calculate that position we just have to apply some linear algebra to the coordinates. To do this I created a structure to hold linear functions:

```
struct LinearFunction {
// for the form y=slope(x) + b
    var slope = CGFloat()
    var b = CGFloat()
}
```

and then used a function to create a linear function for a give set of coordinates.

```
func findEquation(point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint) -> LinearFunction {
        let slope = (point2.y - point1.y) / (point2.x - point1.x)
        let b = point1.y - slope * point1.x
        return LinearFunction(slope: slope, b: b)
    }
```

using these equations we can then go about calculating first the intersect of the two lines and then finding the point directly next to it on the inside of the n-gon

```
func findBallPositionOnEdge(touchPos: CGPoint) -> CGPoint{
//calculate equations for both the wall and the line 
//from the center point to the touch position
        let wallLine = findEquation(point1: startPoint, point2: endPoint)
        let touchLine = findEquation(point1: centerPoint, point2: touchPos)
//calculate the x and y of the intersect of the two lines
        let intersectX = (touchLine.b - wallLine.b) / (wallLine.slope - touchLine.slope)
        let intersectY = (wallLine.slope * intersectX) + wallLine.b
//find the distance from center point to intersect
        let length = (pow(center.x - intersectX, 2) + pow(center.y - intersectY, 2)).squareRoot()
//use the ratio to find the point 10 unit along the line towards the center
        let ratio = 10/length
//calculate the position just inside of the n-gon
        let insidePoint = CGPoint(x: ((1 - ratio) * intersectX) + (ratio * center.x), y:((1 - ratio) * intersectY) + (ratio * center.y))
        return insidePoint
    }
```

I hope this can help some people out who are trying to solve this problem. Probably not the most efficient way to solve the problem, but it looks cleaner than trying to fiddle with physics in my opinion.